# .vce equivalent open format?

Tags: file-format

I'm trying to write my own vce reader (Visual Cert Exam). But .vce is a binary format.

Does exist any way to decode the format? Otherwise, does exist any other equivalent open format?

Comment: There's a project aimed at creating an OEF (Open Exam Format) file designer here, which may be of interest: https://github.com/bolorundurowb/Open-Exam-Suite

Answer (score 18):

So... this question is rather old and I have recently (a few hours over 2 days of investigation so far) been working on this same issue.  The .vce file contains a sqlite database file which is encrypted using AES-256-CBC.  It can apparently be read using the libsqlcipher library which is partly what has gotten me this far.

Really this leaves only 2 missing puzzle pieces.  The offset of the start of the encrypted data and the encryption key.  As for the key, it is either static for all files and or it is generated based on static information about or contained within the plaintext data of the file.  Both of these pieces of information can be found by using reverse engineering.  Once these are found it should be trivial to read and write to vce files.

UPDATE:  There is a public key contained in the player.exe and designer.exe which are used for reading.  The designer also contains a certificate presumably for encryption.

Comment: That is interesting. Have you been able to get any additional details with respect to the missing pieces?

Comment: Considering the key and certificate I found it means it is also using asymmetric encryption in some way.  The public key I am fairly certain is for reading but I haven't spent much time doing any RCE on the binaries.  They keys are easy to find as they are just resources in plaintext in the binaries.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info. I'll be doing some further investigation myself to see if I can create a reader for the VCE files.

Comment: Honestly haven't had time to do much else.  Working on other projects at the moment

Comment: Hi guys, the topic is pretty old so far, but are you able to do further investigation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't really had the time to look more into this.

Comment: Not solved but this Github issue contains additional information on the topic as well as some de-compiled code.https://github.com/bolorundurowb/Open-Exam-Suite/issues/1

Comment: @Goblinlord Any updates on this one guys?

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent open format doesn't exist

Comment: I know of 2 attempts of an open source alternative: the [Open Exam Suite](https://github.com/bolorundurowb/Open-Exam-Suite) and the [Visual Exam Engine](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=visualexamengine) (archived) but you would have to create your own content as there does not seem to be content publicly available at this time.