# How can I analyze a closed format (e.g. doc or vce)?

Tags: binary, format, reverse-engineering, analysis

I want to study the .vce format. It's a binary format and it seems more complicated than a simple object serialization. Does it exist any tool or technique to analyze a binary format?

Comment: Duplicate of your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950882/vce-equivalent-open-format

Comment: In my previous question I was asking an equivalent open format

Answer (score 5):

You might need to "Reverse-Code-Engineer" a programm using this file format (http://www.openrce.org/). Tools used for this kind of analysis are: brain, disassembler (IDA Pro for example) and Debugger (OllyDBG for example). But beware - the way for successfull reverse engineering a file format is veeeeeerrry hard.

And reversing an application might be illegal depending on where you live!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get a library that can read the format (or create one yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would only be possible through some nasty reversed-engineering. It would be very useful to have access to application that uses mentioned format, so that you can generate few simple files and compare them in hex editor. You cannot get far with this method, but you might be able to figure out the header.

It would also be useful to [study some binary format mechanisms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Reverse_Engineering/File_Formats), such as encryption and compression. If you're talking about Visual CertExam file format, than it is likely that useful data will be strongly encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx) is some of the microsoft office binary format specifications

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

- Start by reversing the application reading the files themselves. Particularly android applications are helpful, as the resulting java source is easier to read (you might want to try A+ vce reader for android for example). This program indicates that vce uses/embeds sqlite in the file (in line with what is hinted here: [Reverse Engineer a File Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132402/reverse-engineer-a-file-format)).
- Where to go from here? You might want to explore sqlite file carving tools to see if there might be a way to programatically identify the patterns in the file. Good luck!